# Audio doesn't play?

Tags: audio

I'm new to blender and I just downloaded it. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with the audio. I downloaded a few templates that came with audio but the audio doesn't run. The audio is not muted and my computer sound isn't muted. sometimes I even try to input my own audio and it still doesn't work. Please help since I'm trying to make an intro for my Youtube account.

Comment: How are you adding the audio (Speaker objects? VSE?)? When are you expecting it to play? (in the render? previewing the animation?)

Comment: If using VSE, is the audio strip added?

Comment: Hi Vincent #2!!!

Answer (score 1):

There are so many possible reasons, you need to post more details about the file you're using.

If your file has a movie loaded into VSE, you should have two strips: one for video track, the other for the audio track. Check they are both present, if this is the case.

If your "template" (whatever that means) is using an external audio file, it could be missing or be in a wrong folder (or have a wrong name).

if you look the separate "console" window you could get some message like 
"Warning: Path 'D:\audio\sound.mp3' not found", and other useful messages of what is not working.

If the sound is emitted by a "speaker" object also check that it has not the "mute" checkbox under speaker object data properties. Also VSE audio strips can be muted (muted strips have dotted border)... check audio strip properties (side panel) or the "strip" menu, to change this setting.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a discord call the blender audio won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a 3D hardware acceleration error message before Blender starts, this is likely the source of your non sound issue. I don't know it there is a fix or work around for it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured I'd leave an answer on how I fixed my problem, I had the same problem and that's why I found myself here.

you can also try fixing the **audio output** of blender from

*preferences*
>> System
>> sound
>> Audio Device

and then scroll through the options and see which works