# audio doesn't play at all

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio, windows

I downloaded Blender yesterday primarily to use as a video editor and it worked well, until I tried to play audio. IT'S COMPLETELY MUTE.

I was wearing Bluetooth headphones so I tried using wired headphones and then my laptop's inbuilt speakers and the issue persisted (audio played fine on all other applications by the way).

I tried opening a new project, restarting the program and even restarting my laptop and still no luck. I eventually reinstalled Blender and the audio finally played, so I thought my problem was solved.

A couple hours later my Bluetooth headphones ran out of charge so I plugged in a pair of wired headphones and Blender went mute again (idk if this is related but it happened at the same time so I thought I'd mention it)

I went through the same troubleshooting routine (except for completely reinstalling) and no luck. I'm using the Bluetooth headset again but it's not making any difference.
My laptop runs Windows 10

Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: What are your blender sound settings?    Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33006/audio-doesnt-play   @DuarteFarajotaRamos  some "shouting"  re silence :)_.

Answer (score 1):

In the Preferences, try changing the Audio Device:

[image]